vllm infinite wating error in for loop (multi-gpu)
I was wondering why vllm has infinite waiting error in for loop.
I made attempt_api_call() function which uses vllm to generate answer by given message.
I set up vllm like this:
 (VLLM_TENSOR_PARALLEL_SIZE = 4),
llm = vllm.LLM(
                    model_name,
                    download_dir=os.getenv("HF_HOME"),
                    enforce_eager=True,
                    tensor_parallel_size=VLLM_TENSOR_PARALLEL_SIZE,
                    gpu_memory_utilization=VLLM_GPU_MEMORY_UTILIZATION,
                    trust_remote_code=True,
                    dtype= "half",

                )

then when I execute like this,
for i in range(3):
print(attempt_api_call(args.model, message))
It just waits for infinite time. (Actually, first worker has done generation but other 3 workers are waiting for infinite time)
Error message:
Processed prompts: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:01<00:00,  1.89s/it, est. speed input: 15.88 toks/s, output: 26.47 toks/s]
["Hello! I'm delighted to introduce myself. My name is LLaMA, and I'm a friendly AI assistant here to help you with any questions or tasks you may have. I'm happy to chat with you and provide assistance whenever you need it"]
WARNING 08-08 05:38:54 config.py:1354] Casting torch.bfloat16 to torch.float16.
INFO 08-08 05:38:54 config.py:698] Defaulting to use mp for distributed inference
INFO 08-08 05:38:54 llm_engine.py:169] Initializing an LLM engine (v0.5.1) with config: model='meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct', speculative_config=None, tokenizer='meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct', skip_tokenizer_init=False, tokenizer_mode=auto, revision=None, rope_scaling=None, rope_theta=None, tokenizer_revision=None, trust_remote_code=True, dtype=torch.float16, max_seq_len=8192, download_dir=None, load_format=LoadFormat.AUTO, tensor_parallel_size=4, pipeline_parallel_size=1, disable_custom_all_reduce=False, quantization=None, enforce_eager=True, kv_cache_dtype=auto, quantization_param_path=None, device_config=cuda, decoding_config=DecodingConfig(guided_decoding_backend='outlines'), observability_config=ObservabilityConfig(otlp_traces_endpoint=None), seed=0, served_model_name=meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct, use_v2_block_manager=False, enable_prefix_caching=False)
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=1154012) INFO 08-08 05:38:58 multiproc_worker_utils.py:215] Worker ready; awaiting tasks
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=1154013) INFO 08-08 05:38:58 multiproc_worker_utils.py:215] Worker ready; awaiting tasks
[W socket.cpp:697] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [localhost]:37041 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
(VllmWorkerProcess pid=1154011) INFO 08-08 05:38:58 multiproc_worker_utils.py:215] Worker ready; awaiting tasks
[W socket.cpp:697] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [localhost]:37041 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).
[W socket.cpp:697] [c10d] The client socket cannot be initialized to connect to [localhost]:37041 (errno: 97 - Address family not supported by protocol).

When I execute attempt_api_call() only once, it works well. Also, when I set VLLM_TENSOR_PARALLEL_SIZE=1, it works too. But I have to use multi-gpu, otherwise CUDA OOM happens. I think this problem is because of vllm_tensor_parallel_size and multi-gpu.
Version of vllm is 0.5.1.
I did

export VLLM_WORKER_MULTIPROC_METHOD=spawn
pip install vllm==0.5.0

But none of them works well.
